# Deep Link performance Android

Tags: android, deep-linking

So, what I have observed is if I navigate to some new Activity in my app using  deeplink takes a bit more time as compared to navigating to same Activity using intent.

I understand deeplink takes time to resolve and redirect

Is there any way where I can ensure better performance opening deeplink from app itself

Comment: yes may b u can redirect every deeplink via splash screen

Comment: I don't think it's true. Deeplink are transformed as Intents. Have you some data/logs to confirm this?